# Choosing an alphabet that covers the most words?

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of words and an alphabet that has at most P letters, how can we choose the optimal alphabet that covers the most words?

For example: Given words "aaaaaa" "bb" "bb" with P=1, the optimal alphabet is "b" since "b" covers two words.

Another example: Given words "abmm" "abaa" "mnab" "bbcc" "mnnn" with P=4, the optimal alphabet is "abmn", since that covers 4 of the 5 words.

Are there any known algorithms, or can someone suggest an algorithm that solves this problem?

Comment: How large can P be? And how many distinct letters are there(in all words in total)?

Comment: I'm trying hard to figure out exactly how, but it's not trivial. I do recommend though looking at the dynamic programming pseudo polynomial solution to the knapsack problem, I plan to try in that vein.

Comment: How could the old version of the question receive 9 downvotes, and this blatant second attempt received 10 upvotes?

Answer (score 6):

This problem is NP-hard by reduction from CLIQUE (it's sort of a densest k-sub(hyper)graph problem). Given a graph, label its vertices with distinct letters and, for each edge, make a two-letter word. There exists a k-clique if and only if we can cover k choose 2 words with k letters.

The algorithm situation even for CLIQUE is [grim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Fixed-parameter_intractability) (running times must be n^Theta(k) under a plausible hypothesis), so I'm not sure what to recommend other than brute force with primitive [bit arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).

Comment: Nice reduction, would never have thought of trying CLIQUE!  I was slogging away on 3SAT, making progress, but it's big and ugly...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not yet sure that this is correct, but hopefully it's at least close. We consider a dynamic programming solution. Enumerate the words 1 through N, the letters in our alphabet 1 through P. We want to be able to solve (n, p) in terms of all sub solutions. We consider several cases.

The simplest case is where the nth word is already in the dictionary given in the solution to (n-1, p). We then count ourselves lucky, up the words covered by one, and leave the dictionary unchanged (ddictionary refers to some subset of letters here).

Suppose instead that the nth word is not in the dictionary given by (n-1, p). Then either the dictionary solving (n-1, p) is the dictionary for (n, p), OR the nth word is in the solution. So we look for solutions that explicitly involve the nth word. So, we add all the letters in the nth word to the dictionary we are considering. We now search through all previous subsolutions of the form (n-1, i), where i is p-1 or less. We are looking for the largest value of i such that |d(n-1, i) U d(n)| <= p. Where d(n-1, i) means the dictionary associated with that solution, and d(n) simply means the dictionary associated with all letters of the nth word. In plain English, we use our subsolutions to find the best solution with a smaller value of p that allows us to fit the new word. Once we have found that value of i, we combine the dictionaries whose magnitude we were measuring. If the magnitude of this set is still not p, we repeat the process described before. When we have created a dictionary with magnitude p that covers the nth word with this technique (or iterated through all previous solutions), we compute its coverage and compare it to the coverage we would get by simply using the dictionary from (n-1, p), and we pick the better. If theres a tie, we pick both.

Im not completely convinced of the correctness of this solution, but I think it may be right. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't completely follow parts of your 3rd paragraph, but one difficulty I see is that there can be many different dictionaries that are optimal for some (i <= n, j <= P) solution, and I think they all need to be stored for the first case (when the nth word is already in the dictionary that optimally solves (n-1, P)) to be reliably detected.

Comment: I agree, but storing multiple dictionaries is not that difficult. I think the greater concern is that it may subtly fail in some cases. The solution is modelled after the knapsack problem, but here different capacities of the knapsack are independent, whereas a union of dictionaries may have a coverage greater, equal or less than the sum of the coverage of the two dictionaries independently (where I think the greater case poses the most problems). It may still work out; I thought its worth posting as a decent start though. It doesnt fully answer the question so I can take it down if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

1. Use the input words to create a data structure that maps lists of letters (strings) to the number of words that they cover. You can do this by extracting unique letters that make up a word, sorting them and using the result as a hash map key.
2. Disregard any entries whose keys are longer than P (can't cover those words by our limited alphabet).
3. For all remaining entires, compute a list of entries that are contained by them (an alphabet 'ab' contains the alphabet 'b' and 'a'). Sum the number of words covered by those entries.
4. Find the entry with the highest number of keys.

Answer (score 1):

As David has shown above (with an excellent proof!), this is NP-hard so you won't get a perfect answer in every situation.

One approach to add to the other answers is to express this as a max-flow problem.

Define a source node S, a sink node D, a node for each words, and a node for each letter.

Add edges from S to each word of capacity 1.

Add edges from each word to the letters it contains of infinite capacity.

Add edges from each letter to D of capacity x (where we will define x in a moment).

Then solve for the min-cut of this graph (by using a maximum flow algorithm from S to D).  A cut edge to a letter represents that that letter is not being included in the solution.

This can be thought of as solving the problem where we get a reward of 1 for each word, but it costs us x for each new letter we use.

Then the idea is to vary x (e.g. by bisection) to try and find a value for x where exactly k letter edges are cut.  If you manage this then you will have identified the exact solution to your problem.

This approach is reasonably efficient, but it depends on your input data whether or not it will find the answer.  For certain examples (e.g. David's construction to find cliques) you will find that as you vary x you will suddenly jump from including fewer than k letters to including more than k letters.  However, even in this case you may find that it helps in that it will provide some lower and upper bounds for the maximum number of words in the exact solution.