# How to determine best order to maximise impact

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, python-3.x, solver

*Disclaimer: This question is more related to an algorithm question than a pure python coding (or Excel solver) question*

We are currently migrating 600+ websites to a new platform. Part of the job is about porting the code of our components (30+) to the new platform.
In order to tackle this job, we have inventoried the usage of each component on each site:

[image: Summary of components usage per site]

Now, we should find in which order we are going to port the components.
The base rule is the following: as soon as all components used by a given website is ported, the website can be migrated.

The aim is to maximise the number of sites we can migrate at the earliest possible time.

In my example:

- if we start by porting Comp. B, we won't be able to migrate sites even though Comp. B is heavily used. Therefore I would not start with Comp. B.
- if we start by porting Comp. A, we will be able to migrate Site 2 and move forward with the other site. Therefore, Comp. A is probably a good candidate
- Then, we could move to Comp. C, Comp. D and finally Comp. B

This is fairly easy with 4 components and 5 sites, but is a real nightmare with the amounts we have to deal with.

What would be a systematic approach?

Comment: You should edit the tags to reflect the fact that it's more algorithm than Python/Excel.

Comment: This sounds like a variation of a [Critical path method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method) problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is NP-hard (see this [question for a proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314114/choosing-an-alphabet-that-covers-the-most-words)), with only 30 components you should be able to brute force all combinations by using a variant of [the Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) for the travelling salesman problem.

The main idea is to compute a score, not for each permutation (because there are too many permutations), but for each set of which components you have built.

There will be 2^N sets, which is much smaller than the N! permutations.

To work out the score for each set S, you iterate over the choice of the last component x you added, and add the score for completing all sites which include x (and other components in S) to the previously computed score for the smaller set S-x.  For each set you store the best score available, and which component should be added last.

When you have worked out the score for adding all components, you back track through the stored information to work out the order of adding components.

Answer (score 1):

I'll generalize the number of components you have to `N` ("N" components). Since the order of the of the component refactor affects the amount of sites that can be deployed in that instance of time, this becomes a maximization of permutations.

> The amount of permutations for a set of size `N` is `N!`, or `factorial(N)`

If you have 4 components you will have 24 distinct permutations for the order of component refactoring. From there you can compute the amount of possible sites that could be migrated for each permutations ordering.

You decide which is the "optimal" result. Maximize it by choosing the result that produces the most migrations with the first components refactor, or a sum of component refactors. It's fully dependent on your Business Logic.

Answer (score 0):

Two Algorithms:

**The First** The one you described mostly in your example. This gives the most efficient, and finishes the migration of ALL sites the fastest, but might not be the one that gives more sites up-front

- Arrange all Components by the number of sites using them (ComponentSiteUsageCount).
- Plan Component migrating in the descending orders of ComponentSiteUsageCount.
- Give a date for each component migration delivery (CompomentMigrationDate)
- Once a data is given for each component, Plan site migration. A site can be migrated when all its components are migrated:

  -- For each site, iterate through all Components by ComponentMigrationDate   starting by the last ComponentMigrationDate. While iterating, check if the site has that Component, and the first Component the site has is the SiteMigrationDate.

**The second** is likely to produce more sites migrated faster

- Produce a list of all Components. For each Component in the list, produce the count of Sites only having remaining dependency on this Component (SitesPendingOn). Take the one with the most, and assign it a MigrationOrder (ascending number). If there are no such Components remaining in the list, produce the count of Site usage for each remaining (not assigned Migration order): ComponentSiteUsageCount. Take the one with the most, and assign it the next MigrationOrder. Repeat looping on the Components not assigned MigrationOrder to get the SitesPendingOn until all components have assigned MigrationOrder
- For each site, iterate through all Components by ComponentMigrationDate   starting by the last ComponentMigrationDate. While iterating, check if the site has that Component, and the first Component the site has is the SiteMigrationDate.

**Code for Second Algorithm**
'

```
import pandas as pd

def get_pending_sites(site_components, component, components):
    count = 0
    for index, site in site_components.iterrows():
        #print('site ...', site['Site'])
        if site[component] > 0. and components[component][0] == 0:
            #print('site uses component')
            other_dependent = False
            for site_component in list(site_components.columns.values)[1:]:
                if site_component != component:
                    if site[site_component] > 0. and components[site_component][0] == 0:
                        #print('site uses other components')
                        other_dependent = True
                        break
            if other_dependent == False:
                count += 1
    #print('count', count)
    return count                

def get_used_sites(site_components, component):
    count = len(site_components[site_components[component] > 0.])
    print ("Component: ", component, " used in sites: ", count)
    return count

def get_most_pending_sites(components):
    most_count = 0
    most_component = None
    for component in components:
        if components[component][0] == 0:
            count = components[component][1]
            if count > most_count:
                most_component = component
                most_count = count
            elif (count == most_count) and (most_component != None):
                if components[component][2] > components[most_component][2] :
                    most_component = component
    return most_component

def get_most_used_sites(components):
    most_count = 0
    most_component = None
    for component in components:
        if components[component][0] == 0:
            count = components[component][2]
            if count > most_count:
                most_component = component
                most_count = count
    return most_component

migration_order = 1
site_components = pd.read_csv('site_components.csv')
#print(site_components.describe())

components = dict.fromkeys(list(site_components.columns.values)[1:])
for component in components:
    components[component] = [0, 0, 0]
    components[component][2] = get_used_sites(site_components, component)

#print(components)

while True:
    print("Components: ", components)
    for component in components:
        if components[component][0] == 0:
            print('starting .....', component)
            components[component][1] = get_pending_sites(site_components, component, components)
            print('finished .....', component, components[component][1], components[component][2])


    while True:
        most_pending_sites_component = get_most_pending_sites(components)
        print('most pending sites components: ', most_pending_sites_component)
        if most_pending_sites_component != None:
            components[most_pending_sites_component][0] = migration_order
            migration_order = migration_order + 1
        else:
            break

    most_used_sites_component = get_most_used_sites(components)
    if most_used_sites_component != None:
        components[most_used_sites_component][0] = migration_order
        migration_order = migration_order + 1
    else:
        break

# order of migration in [0]
print("Components: ", components)
```

**Assumption**: The time it takes to migrate a component is uniform across all components
**Note**: Save the spreadsheet that has the sites and components as csv, and remove all totals vertical and horizontal

Comment: Aside from a probable typo where 'return len(site_components[site_components['Component1'] > 0.])' should probably replaced by 'return len(site_components[site_components[component] > 0.])', I don't really know how to interprete the results (in this particular example: {'comp. A': [4, 5, 5], 'comp. B': [3, 0, 1], 'comp. C': [2, 0, 4], 'comp. D': [1, 0, 4]}). If I understand you correctly, I should go A then B, then C, then D? which does not match my previous instinct.

Comment: The difference between Algorithm 1 and 2 is that in the second, you check to see if there's a site that is only dependent on a single component to be completed - that component (or the one with max sites with single dependency on component) is given priority. And keep iterating. If no such site, you take the site with max dependencies, and then return to the first step. I have modified few issues I had not the time to test before. Have a look